# Is it inappropriate to eat or drink while reading the Torah?

Tags: tefilla, torah-study, eating, drinking

Just a general question. This does not involve reciting tehillim or reading passages out loud. Just quiet reading. If not appropriate — sources?

Comment: It appears to be a completely different question. The other refers to general learning, or saying Divrei Torah over food. This seems more specific - "Can one eat or drink while **reading Torah** either from a scroll or a Chumash"?

Comment: @AlBerko, thank you for making that valid point. Maybe there will be some feedback now.